# A nim game with 4 piles

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

In the game of Nim there are 4 piles sizes 9,10,11,12.
Im trying to figure out who has the winning strategy, is it an N-position or P position state.

Comment: Do you know the general strategy for Nim...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the XOR of the numbers in binary and you get $0100_2$.  Since it is not zero, this is an N position.  You need to find a move that makes it zero.  Take four from the twelve pile.